# How can I Define an Async Action in c#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, delegates, action

I really want to know if there is a way to define action variables `async`? Or some alternative method?

```
public System.Action myAction;

public async System.Action myAsyncAction;
void Start()
{
    // normal action
    myAction += () =>
    {
        Debug.Log("Inject some code in runtime..");
    };

    // I want something like this that support wait time..
    myAsyncAction += () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000f);
        
        Debug.Log("Inject some code in runtime..");
    };
}
```

Comment: But Action is for `void`, and awaitables return something like a Task if they have no result value, or Task<T> if they have a result value. In either case the Task is the return value, so they aren't void (aren't Actions). Don't strive for ways to await void ;)

Comment: The case that Clinton mentioned. Fixed the problem. In fact, I was looking for a way to add code to the body during runtime. :)) thank u guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used `Func<Task>` in the past. EG:

```cs
Func<Task> asyncMethod = async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("done here");
};

await asyncMethod();
```

Comment: Think there might be a better suffix than "..Action"

Comment: Fair enough @CaiusJard, changed to `asyncMethod`

Comment: Between `asyncAction` and `asyncMethod`, I would prefer the former. :-)